# simultaneously two module load in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
var moduleA=angular.module("MyModuleA",[]);
  moduleA.controller("MyControllerA",function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Bob A";
 });
var moduleB=angular.module("MyModuleB",[]);
moduleB.controller("MyControllerB", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Steve B";
});
var main = angular.module("CombineModule", ["MyModuleA", "MyModuleB"]);
 main.controller("main",function($scope){
   $scope.loadModuleA = function(){
    console.log("Load module 'A' ")
  }; 
   $scope.loadModuleB = function(){
   console.log("Load module 'B' ")
  }; 
});
```

I want to load two module simultaneously  when I click on module A and module B button

Comment: What do you mean by load? Do you want to use a given controller? You might, have a separation of concerns issue.

Comment: What is the question. You tell what you want, but not what problem you encounter and where you need help. If we should read the last sentence as "How can I load two modules simultaneously when I click on the module A and the module B button?" If so update your post with that, and explain if anything should happen at all if one of the two is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app="CombineModule" ng-controller="main">
      <button ng-click="loadModuleA()">Load Module A</button>
      <button ng-click="loadModuleB()">Load Module B</button>
        <div>
            <h1>myDiv1</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerA">
                {{name}}{{app}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>myDiv2</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerB">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

load module A on click Module A button and load modle B on click on module B
```